# How do I unzip all directories in a specific subdirectory of a .JAR file using the unzip command in Windows 10 Bash?

Tags: windows, unzip

I have a .Jar file, let's call it Test.jar. Inside this file are several directories: Alpha, Beta, Gamma. Alpha and Gamma I don't care about. Beta contains three directories (Uno, Dos, Tres), and those are the ones I want.

I'm trying to use the bash shell on Windows 10, and specifically the unzip command, to target those files and unzip them. The closest I've managed to get looks something like this:

unzip -o C:/directory/test.jar Beta/* -d c:/directory/output

What I would like to see is Uno, Dos, and Tres inside the output folder. Instead, I see nothing.

If I put a file inside the Beta directory (ex. file.txt) and re-run the command, file.txt will be unzipped, but all of the directories are ignores.

If I remove the "Beta/*" from the command unzip happily unzips all directories and files.

I've tried playing around with a wide variety of quotes in different places, but I can't seem to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
unzip 123.zip  -x "Alpha/*" "Beta/*" -d $HOME
```

That will unzip everthing except the contents of the directories Alpha and Beta into your home profile location named $HOME.